# Issue with Glassfish Server on AIX 7.1

Tags: java, glassfish, aix

I want to use Glassfish Server on AIX machine. I installed the Glassfish Software and I don't want to use System Java Version with Glassfish.

So I installed the java on another location and edited the asenv_bk.conf file to set JAVA_HOME with "AS_JAVA"

after firing command "./asadmin start-domain" I am receiving error

> ./asadmin: /appltech/glassfish/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: 0403-006 Execute permission denied.

Need guidance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command `ls -l /appltech/glassfish/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java` to see the permissions for the `java` binary.

On my Linux system, I get this:

> ➜  ~ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7734 Jan 20 08:10 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

The important bit is the first few letters and dashes (`-rwxr-xr-x`) and the `root root` part.

This is telling you the following:

1. the first dash tells you that the target is a file, not a directory (the first `-` would be a `d` if it was a directory)
2. the next 3 characters are `rwx` which mean the **owner** of the file has permissions to `r`ead, `w`rite (modify) and e`x`ecute the file
3. the next 3 characters are `r-x`, meaning that users in the right **group** can read and execute, but **not** write or modify
4. the last 3 characters are `r-x` and give the same permissions to the **current user** as are given to the group.
5. Finally, the `root root` part tells you that the owner of the file is `root` and the group is `root`.

I expect that the `x` flag will be missing from your `java` binary, so to add that for all users you will need to run:

`chmod +x /appltech/glassfish/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java`

You will probably need to run the `chmod` command as a user with elevated permissions (e.g. root)